# How can I create ribbon area for a time series data with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize time series data. I have set of **5 loggers** which are indicating snow movement distance and an **environmental variable** that possibly has an effect on the snow movement. That is why it is meaningful to graph them together to see if snow movement (detected by the loggers) is influenced by these environmental factors. I have a file containing **the weather station data** and **5 files for each logger**. The weather data is measured **every 5 minutes** while the loggers measure **whenever there is movement**! I have managed to visualize them together so far, however, my professor wants me to visualize the loggers as a group by presenting **a gray area** (instead of 5 lines) that always shows the minimum and maximum value of the loggers at a certain time point. I am using **ggplot2**. I've tried to make such area by using ribbon **geom_ribbon** but it is not so straight forward with my dataset. The line are crossing and often the loggers that have the min and max value switch. I don't know if joining them in a single dataset would help but this is also not possible because they don't have the same length. Furthermore, its not like all 5 loggers have measurements at the same time. They log only when there is movement. Here is my code and the graph that it creates. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to reproduce the data. I am more than glad to share it with you somehow.

```
#install.packages("patchwork")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(patchwork)

Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "english")

startTime <- as.Date("2017-10-01")
endTime <- as.Date("2018-06-30")
start_end <- c(startTime,endTime)

################################################## FALL LINE 1 #########################################################

logger1 <- read.csv("F1_17_18_167.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";")
logger1$date <- as.Date(logger1$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")

logger2 <- read.csv("F1_17_18_186.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";")
logger2$date <- as.Date(logger2$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")

logger3 <- read.csv("F1_17_18_031.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";")
logger3$date <- as.Date(logger3$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")

logger4 <- read.csv("F1_17_18_091.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";")
logger4$date <- as.Date(logger4$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")

logger5 <- read.csv("F1_17_18_294.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";")
logger5$date <- as.Date(logger5$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")

station <- read.csv("aggregates.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
station$date <- as.Date(station$Group.1, "%Y-%m-%d")


ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = station, aes(x = date, y = Mean_snowheight ,color = "Mean Snowheight"),na.rm = TRUE, size = 1)+
  scale_x_date(limits=start_end,breaks=date_breaks("1 month"),labels=date_format("%b %y"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c (0,115))

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = logger1, aes(x = date, y = AccuDist, color = "167 (mid-bottom)"),na.rm= TRUE, size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = logger2, aes(x = date, y = AccuDist, color = "186 (top-middle)"),na.rm= TRUE, size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = logger3, aes(x = date, y = AccuDist, color = "31 (top)"),na.rm= TRUE, size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = logger4, aes(x = date, y = AccuDist, color = "91 (bottom)"),na.rm= TRUE, size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = logger5, aes(x = date, y = AccuDist, color = "294 (middle)"),na.rm= TRUE, size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = station, aes(x = date, y = Mean_snowheight*11.49 ,color = "Mean snowheight"),na.rm = TRUE, size = 1) +
  ggtitle("Fall line 1") +
  labs(color = "")+
  xlab("Season 17/18")+
  ylab("Accumulated Distance [mm]")+
  scale_x_date(limits=start_end,breaks=date_breaks("1 month"),labels=date_format("%b %y"))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./11.49,name = "Mean snowheight [cm]"),limits = c(0,1500))+
  scale_color_manual("", guide = "legend",
                     values = c("167 (mid-bottom)"= "darkorange2",
                                "186 (top-middle)" = "darkgreen",
                                "31 (top)" = "red",
                                "91 (bottom)" = "blue",
                                "294 (middle)" = "purple",
                                "Mean snowheight" = "black"))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        #legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, size = 10 , vjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, vjust = 0.5), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightblue"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22))
```

You can see what graph this code produces:

[image: ggplot2]

If you ignore the environmental factor for a second (black line) you are left the **accumulated** snow movement distance over the winter period for each logger (the colored lines). My aim is to fill the area that is always between the lowest and highest line.

Let me know if I need to upload the data somewehere. This is how it the logger data looks like: [data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9u7R.jpg).

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Zorin

Comment: I think I can help you here, but are you able to upload your dataset?  In order to share some data, please, don't share files (files can be corrupted and links are dangerous here), but please load as a dataset and share the output of `dput(dataset)`.  Can you at least share for 2 or 3 of the logger datasets in this manner?  The text output from `dput()` can be pretty long (depending on your dataset), so you can always use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to share the output.  We then copy and paste that to recreate the df as it was for you.

Comment: Hello @chemdork123,

Thanks for the swift response. Here is the output. I am not sure if I did it the way you wanted. For some of the loggers I managed to copy the whole output. For other loggers and the station data I created the largest possible subset.

[Logger1](https://pastebin.com/C9PHVKsa)
[Logger2](https://pastebin.com/dtmNNtRg)
[Logger3](https://pastebin.com/mFf9f9c6)
[Logger4](https://pastebin.com/VgzdktJz)
[Logger5](https://pastebin.com/pYg1Vafc)
[Station (weather) data](https://pastebin.com/PnQddaSR)

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Zorin

Comment: @chemdork123 Also I need to clarify that this line in the code above can be ignored. I just use to assist the approximation of the scaling of the secondary axis.

`ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = station, aes(x = date, y = Mean_snowheight ,color = "Mean Snowheight"),na.rm = TRUE, size = 1)+
  scale_x_date(limits=start_end,breaks=date_breaks("1 month"),labels=date_format("%b %y"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c (0,115))`

Comment: I think that should work out fine.  even subsets of data work out pretty well.  I will try to put together a workable example of how I would approach the challenge here.  I think all I'll need is the "logger" datasets, but let me have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a tougher than it seems at first.  Your goal as I understand is to fill in the area in your line plot between the "lowest" and the "highest" lines.  This is made more difficult by the fact what is the lowest and highest line may change places throughout the plot, so you cannot simply choose to plot between one of the logs and another log.  It's also made difficult by the fact that your x axis value is a date, so not all logs collect data on the same date and time.

First of all, I'll be ignoring a bit of your personal aesthetics you added and also removing the line you included for Mean snow height (from the dataframe `station`) for ease of showing you the solution I have.

#### Data Preparation

To begin, I noticed that you have included a `geom_line()` call for each individual logging station dataset (`logger1` through `logger5`).  While the method certainly works (and you do it in a way that gives you the solution you desire), it's much better practice to combine all logs into one dataset and this is going to be necessary in order for the solution I'm proposing to work anyway.  Luckily, it's pretty simple to do this: just use `rbind()` to combine the datasets.  Critically - you'll need to create a new column for each (called `id` here) that maintains the identity of the logging station of origin.  You can then use that new `id` column as your `color=` aesthetic and draw all 5 lines using one `geom_line()` call.

One small problem I ran into is that your datasets had slightly different column names (some were caps, some were not...).  They were all in the same order, so it wasn't too difficult to make them all the same before combining... it just added another step.  Finally, I converted the `date` column to date format.

```
# create the id column
logger1$id <- 'logger1'
logger2$id <- 'logger2'
logger3$id <- 'logger3'
logger4$id <- 'logger4'
logger5$id <- 'logger5'

# fixing inconsistency in column names
my_column_names <- names(logger1)

names(logger2) <- my_column_names
names(logger3) <- my_column_names
names(logger4) <- my_column_names
names(logger5) <- my_column_names

# make one big df
loggers <- rbind(logger1, logger2, logger3, logger4, logger5)

loggers$date <- as.Date(loggers$date)
```

You can now recreate the plot in a more simple way:

```
ggplot(loggers, aes(x=date, y=AccuDist)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(aes(color=id), size=1)
```

[image]

#### Finding the Running Minimum and Maximum

In order to create the fill, I'm using `geom_ribbon()`, which needs aesthetics `ymin` and `ymax`.  You have to set those first though, and they need to be "running minimum" and the "running maximum", which means they will change as you progress through the data.  For this, I'm using two functions shown below `min_vect()` and `max_vect()`.

```
# find the "running maximum"
max_vect <- function(ac) {
  curr_max <- 0
  return_vector <- vector(mode = 'numeric', length=length(ac))
  for(i in 1:length(ac)) {
    if(ac[i] > curr_max) {
      curr_max <- ac[i]
    }
    return_vector[i] <- curr_max
  }
  return(return_vector)
}

# find the "running minimum"
min_vect <- function(ac) {
  curr_min <- max(ac)
  return_vector <- vector(mode = 'numeric', length=length(ac))
  for(i in length(ac):1) {
    if(ac[i] < curr_min) {
      curr_min <- ac[i]
    }
    return_vector[i] <- curr_min
  }
  return(return_vector)
}
```

The idea is that for the maximum, you step through an (ordered) vector and if the number is higher than the previous maximum number, it becomes the new maximum.  The same strategy is used for the running minimum, albeit we have to step through the ordered vector in reverse.

In order to apply the functions to create new columns, the dataset needs to be ordered first in order for it to work properly:

```
# must arrange by date and time first!
loggers <- loggers %>% arrange(date, TIME)

# add your new columns
loggers$min_Accu <- min_vect(loggers$AccuDist)
loggers$max_Accu <- max_vect(loggers$AccuDist)
```

#### The Finale

And now, the plot.  Basically it's the same, and I'm using `geom_ribbon()` as described above.  For a bonus, I'm also using `scale_color_discrete()` to set the legend title and labels, just to show you that you can code that in afterwards (and it will still be easier than having separate `geom_line()` calls.

```
logger_list <- c('Log 1', 'Log 2', 'Log 3', 'Log 4', 'Log 5')

ggplot(loggers, aes(x=date, y=AccuDist)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min_Accu, ymax=max_Accu), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(color=id), size=1) +
  scale_color_discrete(name='Log ID Num', labels=logger_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you boss. I transformed it according to my needs and it works good. Thanks for the suggestion to merge my loggers. I should really learn to create functions with "for" and "if" loops.

Comment: Glad it's working out for you!  If you have some regular processing that happens (like what is apparently going on here), you can always combine all that code into a script (*.R file) and then `source()` that to run it in the console.   It's definitely the way to go for combining that data.  Otherwise, yeah `for` loops can work out.  If you have a specific question on how to do that or how to improve on what you do now, I would suggest posting another question on SO.

Comment: Bless you man. Yeah R is amazing. I really should get better at it. It has so much potential. As a student, money is a factor and I cannot afford a personal copy of STATISTICA. It is a main goal of mine to get familiar with R :)

Comment: Well worth it.  If you want some quality "basic R" and "basic data analysis" stuff, I highly recommend the `swirl` package in R.  Install, load the library, then run `swirl()` in the Rstudio console and you will have a really good tutorial on various core R concepts right in the console.  It's basically how I started out and there's a great explanation of the basics of Tidy data (the approach that combined your logger files above).  For me, it was far better than any online course.

Comment: Will definitely check it out !